# Android App Closes on creation?

Tags: android, fatal-error

I am fairly new to android and the app shuts down immediately after creation. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

A little about the app, I am creating a text based adventure and I have all the code coded into java already, and I know the java code works because I have a JavaGui created and working for it. I am now trying to bring this java game to android.

Here is my error log

```
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.coalbolttproductions.russell/com.coalbolttproductions.russell.AdventureToCandyIslandActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.coalbolttproductions.russell.AdventureToCandyIslandActivity.<init>(AdventureToCandyIslandActivity.java:15)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-29 09:19:01.989: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  ... 11 more
```

Here is my main.xml that I believe is the true cause of my problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="25dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command"
        android:password="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Try Command" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Due to popular demand here is the java code from my Adventure class. **Line 15 is the Button chkCmd**

```
public class AdventureToCandyIslandActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    EditText input;
    TextView display;

    Game gameModel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Run the methods
        createVars();
        chkCmd.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void createVars(){
        gameModel = new Game();
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
        display.setText(gameModel.printWelcome());
        display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        display.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String inputLine = input.getText().toString();
        Command command = Command.getCommand(inputLine);
        String result = gameModel.processCommand(command);
        if(result.equals("EXIT")) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            display.append("--------------------------------\n" + result + "\n");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: As the stack trace says the Activity `AdventureToCandyIslandActivity` is failing to start because of a Null pointer somewhere. It would help us a lot if you could show the code from this.

Comment: `AdventureToCandyIslandActivity.java` see line no  15

Comment: You can't initialise the button in the class loader, do it after setting content view.

Comment: ACCEPT THE ANSWER WHICH WAS MOST USEFUL TO YOU by clicking the check sign provided with each answer.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever view you are setting up is returning `null` have you double checked the ID is correct and that `setContentView(R.layout.xxx)` is pointing at the correct file?

Also if you have different layouts defined for portrait and landscape this can cause similar issues if the IDs of your views don't match.AdventureToCandyIslandActivity.java see line no 15

**EDIT**

`Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);`
You've initialised the button in the class loader, if you initialise it in the same place as the other views it will be fine.

Comment: Hmm, I am only using vertical landscape in my layout and I am sure that my setContentView is correct. The xml I pasted above is titled main.xml which is what I open in my ATCI activity

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGE**

```
Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
EditText input;
TextView display;

Game gameModel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**TO THIS**

```
Button chkCmd;
EditText input;
TextView display;

Game gameModel;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```

AS before SETTING THE LAYOUT, You can not initialize the button which is a part of that layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```

You have used **findViewById(R.id.bResults)** before setting ContentView so use following code after removing it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
```